# convert XML attributes inot HTML tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have XML that (slightly simplified) looks like this:

```
<title>
  <style face="normal">Plain</style>
  <style face="bold">Bold</style>
  <style face="italic">Italics
    <style face="bold">italics and bold</style>
  just italics</style>
</title>
```

The `style` nodes can be nested multiple levels deep.
I want to convert the "face" attributes to html-tags, i.e. the above should turn into something like

```
Plain<b>Bold</b><i>Italics<b>italics and bold</b>just italics</i>
```

This is part of a larger xml file that I'm reading into a javascript object, so this needs to happen in javascript. Conceptually I just want to start at the lowest level and go outward, but I can't find a good way of doing this. Without nesting, circling through all `style` nodes with something simple like.

```
var htmlstring = "";
if (node.attributes.face.value == "italic"){
  htmlstring += "<i>" + node.textContent + "</i>"
}
```

would do. But obviously that won't work as soon as I have nesting.
There has got to be an elegant solution for this that I'm just overlooking, right?

Comment: What are you using to parse the XML?  Just curious because something like this becomes easier with a utility like jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the children of `node` recursively:

```
function replaceStyles(node) {
    var htmlstr = "";
    (function repl(node) {
        if (!node) {
            return;
        }
        if (node.attributes && 
            node.attributes.face &&
            node.attributes.face.value == "italic") {
            // I'm just building up a simple string, but you can
            // do whatever you need to with each element here
            htmlstr += "<i>" + node.textContent + "</i>";
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            repl(node.children[i], htmlstr);
        }

    })(node);
    return htmlstr;
}
```

This is a very common problem when working with a tree-like structure. You want to apply some function to `node` and then do the same thing for each of its children and then each of their children (and so on). It's so common, in fact, that there are entire programming languages (e.g. XSLT) designed to work on problems of this type.

Comment: great, that gets me half way there — remaining problem is that this adds child nodes after their parents, rather than into them — in the example above, I get <i>Italics italics and bold just italics</i><b>italics and bold</b>. I think I should be able to replace that in, working on that now.

Comment: Oh, yes. This example is just building up a string, appending to it once for each node. It's just an example. You'll need to do the actual replacements.

Answer (score 1):

This uses jQuery for brevity.  Let me know if you need a pure JS solution.

NOTE: I realize the OP didn't ask for jQuery.

```
var xml = $.parseXML('<title><style face="normal">Plain</style><style face="bold">Bold</style><style face="italic">Italics<style face="bold">italics and bold</style>just italics</style></title>'),
    $title = $( xml ).find('title'),
    $styles,
    htmlString = '';

while( ($styles = $title.find('style')).length ) {
    $styles.each(function() {
        var $style = $(this);
        switch( $style.attr('face') ) {
            case "bold":
                $style.replaceWith('<b>' + $style.html() + '</b>');
                break;
            case "italic":
                $style.replaceWith('<i>' + $style.html() + '</i>');
                break;

            default:
                $style.replaceWith('<span>' + $style.html() + '</span>');
                break;
        }
    });
}

console.log( $title.html() );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/dr29J/

Comment: thanks - unfortunately this is run inside a [Zotero](https://github.com/zotero/zotero) importer, so jQuery is out. Should have specified that.

Comment: No worries.  jQuery just made it quicker to put up a working example.